# Algebraic over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following problem I'm trying to solve it is below.

> Let $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{20}$, then put $F=\{a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+a_3\alpha^3:a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\in \Bbb Q\}$.
>
> The questions are:
>
> (i) Prove that $F=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and
> (ii) evaluate $(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}$ as an element of $F$ and verify your answer.

My attempt is as follows

(i) $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{20}$ $=>\alpha^4-20=0$

Now let $m(x)=x^4-20$ then $m(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ and $m(x)$ is monic

Now $m(\alpha)=\alpha^4-20=0$ thus $m(x)$ is the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$ $<=> m(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$

Now $m(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$ and is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$ by E.I.T using prime $5$, and since $m(x)$ is irred in $\Bbb Z[x]$ this implies $m(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$

So $x^4-20$ is the min poly of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$ since $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$
thus $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=deg(m(x))=4$.

Thus $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ is a basis for $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ over $\Bbb Q$

Thus $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=a_0+a_1(\alpha)+a_2(\alpha^2)+a_3(\alpha^3):a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\in \Bbb Q=F$ as required

This is the end of my solution for part (i) I can't see anywhere I'm going wrong with this part but I put it on here in case I have made an error somewhere?

part (ii)

Evaluate $(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}$

Put $g(x)=1+x^3)$ then I need to show that the $gcd(m(x),g(x))=1$ as I need to find an $R(x),S(x):1=R(x)(1+x^3)+S(x)(x^4-20)$

this is as far as I have got, I dont know where to go from here so any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#B.C3.A9zout.27s_identity)?

Comment: i thought that was just for real numbers, can you do that for functions also?

Comment: As long as you are in a ring with division with remainder (as polynomials and integers), you can apply the algorithm to obtain the greatest common divisor together with an identity of the desired form.

Comment: i'm getting stuck with the long division its stressful

Comment: You don't need to do any polynomial division. Just expand $(1 + \alpha^3)(a_0 + a_1 \alpha + a_2 \alpha^2 + a_3 \alpha^3)$ using $\alpha^4 = 20$ and then equate coefficients with $1 = 1 + 0\alpha + 0\alpha^2 + 0\alpha^3$.

Comment: okay, is that the same for $\alpha^4-20$ as well?

Comment: In the field you are interested in $\alpha^4 - 20 = 0$, i.e., $\alpha^4 = 20$. The recipe I have given you will allow you to find the inverse of any non-zero element.

Comment: okay thanks for the clarification, is the first part correct btw?

Comment: The first part looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do any polynomial division. In part (i), you have proved $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has $1, \alpha, \alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$ as a basis over $\Bbb{Q}$. In part (ii) you use this: to invert $1 + \alpha^3$, you have to solve:
$$
\begin{align*}
1 &= (1 + \alpha^3)(a_0 + a_1\alpha + a_2\alpha^2 + a_3\alpha^3)\\
  &= (a_0 + 20a_1) + (a_1 + 20a_2)\alpha + (a_2 + 20a_3)\alpha^2 + (a_3 + a_0)\alpha^3
\end{align*}
$$
where the second equation follows by multiplying out and using $\alpha^4 = 20$.
By part (i), the coefficients of $\alpha^3$, $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha$ must be zero and the constant term must be $1$, so you must have:
$$
\begin{array}{rllr}
a_3 &= -a_0 &\\
a_2 &= -20a_3 &= 20a_0\\
a_1 &= -20a_2 &= -400a_0\\
a_0 &= 1 -20a_1 &= 1 + 8000a_0
\end{array}
$$
Now you can easily solve the last equation for $a_0$ and read off the other $a_i$, to get
$$
(1 + \alpha^3)^{-1} = \frac{1}{7999}(-1 + 400\alpha -20\alpha^2 + \alpha^3).
$$

Comment: may i ask why we set 1= to your first line in the answer?

Comment: and also what part of (i) indicates why $\alpha^3,\alpha^2, \alpha$ mut be zero and then why is the constant term equal to 1?

Comment: scratch that i know why 1= the first line, its since $S(x)(x^4-20)=0$ as $x^4-20=0$ since it is the min poly

Comment: @Gibberish: The first line is just the equation $1 = ab$ that you have to solve to find the inverse $b = a^{-1}$ of an element $a$ of a ring. You can solve this by equating coefficients using the fact that the ring $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has $1$, $\alpha$, $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$ as a basis over $\Bbb{Q}$ (proved by the OP in part (i)) and the equation $\alpha^4 = 20$, which holds in $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ by definition of $\alpha$.

Comment: yeah i understand that part but why from part (i) can we assume that $\alpha^3,\alpha^2,\alpha=0$ is it because we just want to evaluate $1+\alpha^3$?

Comment: @Gibberish: please note the use of the term **basis** in the question, my answer and my reply to your comment.

Comment: could you expand on your solution, i dont understand how you've gotten to the result. how can we easily solve the last equation for a0 and read off the others? its confusing

Comment: i managed to obtain the same solution using long division but i would like to see how you do the above as it would really save some time during an exam.

Comment: since the long division method takes a while.

Comment: Which part of the answer are you having difficulty with?

Comment: It's okay now I've figured it out thanks though

Answer (score 3):

Computing $(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}$ looks a little hairy using the extended Euclidean algorithm, but you can pull a little trick: first compute $(\alpha+20)^{-1}$ since that will terminate in a single long division, and then note that $\alpha(\alpha+20)^{-1}=(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}$

So, to be explicit:

$\alpha^4 - 20 = (\alpha^3 - 20 \alpha^2 + 400 \alpha - 8000) (\alpha + 20) + 159980$,

and you already have

$(\alpha + 20)^{-1}\equiv \frac{\alpha^3 - 20 \alpha^2 + 400 \alpha - 8000}{-159980}$

Then multiplying by $\alpha$ you get

$$
(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}\equiv\frac{\alpha^4 - 20 \alpha^3 + 400 \alpha^2 - 8000\alpha}{-159980}\\ \equiv\frac{20- 20 \alpha^3 + 400 \alpha^2 - 8000\alpha}{-159980}\\ \equiv\frac{1-  \alpha^3 + 20 \alpha^2 - 400\alpha}{-7999}
$$

Comment: should that be $(\alpha^4-20)^{-1}$

Comment: @Gibberish No, $\alpha^4-20=0$, and it doesn't have an inverse. Rereading what I wrote, I'm still pretty sure it's fine as written. Just look at $\alpha^{-1}(1+\alpha^3)^{-1}=(\alpha+\alpha^4)^{-1}$

Comment: Since it's only one iteration of long-division, it's the easiest method I've thought of so far.

Comment: As I said in a comment on the question, you don't need to do any polynomial division. I've written it up as an answer.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree your approach is better than three iterations with the original pair of values, but this method only uses one division. I think this is still probably easier than multiplying everything out and solving. All the coefficients get precomputed, and you don't have to do any backsolving.

Comment: @rschwieb: I disagree (particularly as you felt the need for a trick to reduce the number of divisions). I think the OPs problem is meant to be standard drill on computing in an algebraic extension of a field.

Comment: @RobArthan Well, the last things I'll say on the matter are: your parenthetical mark is absurd; and I am on board with your last sentence, but I do no think it justifies deliberate action to pull down alternative solutions; and by my rough calculations, it looks like they use about the same number of operations. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb: I was only disagreeing about how easy the solutions are to find: my parenthetical remark just means that I think this is intended to be a routine exercise rather than one that requires tricks. Thanks for filling in the details of your solution, so that the two approaches can be compared objectively.